# Как назвать модуль?

Tags: c++, delphi

Есть модуль со вспомогательными функциями, который используется во множестве проектов. Как его можно назвать?

Comment: А Вы не думали назвать сообразно его функционалу?.. Обычно делают так.

Comment: Попробуйте: `Utils`

Comment: @AivanF, модуль "вспомогательный", как большая библиотека, которую везде с собой таскаю. Понятно, что должен отражать функционал и назначение, но, по моему скромному мнению, всякие там "helper"-ы в папке с проектом - это колхоз =(

Comment: @Robert ну блин, а что он делает? У меня тоже полно всяких вспомогательных либ. Помогает обрабатывать текст - `StrProcessor`, производит важные операции для отрисовки - `NetVisualizer`, обрабатывает нестандартно стандартные коллекции - `ContainerMaestro`; и т.д., и т.п. Ну а если у Вас сборник всего и вся - то чего-то лучше helper'a или utilites можно и не ждать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обзовите очевидным образом:
    RobertUtils

Comment: А если модулем потом с кем-нибудь придется поделиться? :) Я люблю более универсальные названия

Comment: @Robert Тогда `zUTv_14T6y_rrWS18`...

Comment: @Harry, такое название не отражает содержимого. Модуль "вспомогательный"

Comment: @Robert Ну тогда `auxiliary_module` :)

Comment: @Harry, звучит некрасиво(

Comment: @Robert http://namegenerator.ru/

Comment: Назовите atomic_modulе и никому не давайте. Всем бы Ваши заботы!